# If I use async/await, it doesn't run in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have a question about the async/await execution.

example codes

```js
async firstMethod(){
  new Promise((resolve, reject)) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("test1");
     }, 3000);     
  });
}

async secondMethod() {
  new Promise((resolve, reject)) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("test2");
     }, 1000);     
  });
}

await firstMethod();
await secondMethod();
```

So, When the two methods are executed, the following results are obtained.

```
test2
test1
```

However, if a return is attached, the result value is as follows.

```js
async firstMethod(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("test1");
     }, 3000);     
  });
}

async secondMethod() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("test2");
     }, 1000);     
  });
}

await firstMethod();
await secondMethod();
```

```
test1
test2
```

Why is that? I'd appreciate it if you could explain it.

Comment: Because without the return, your methods don't return the promise to await. They return a promise of undefined instead, unrelated to the `new Promise`s.

Comment: I argued against this behaviour (`await` on non-promises automatically `Promise.resolve`ing) and lost.

Comment: The post shows two sets of results. Can you edit the post to show where and how they were produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you just await the outer promises (that are the `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` functions) and the inner promises created by `new Promise` do not get awaited, and simply run to completion in the background.

In the second case, because of *promise unwrapping* you await the returned inner promises *together* with the outer function promises.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why in the first example those 2 functions do not run in order is because you are not waiting for anything. If you try to remove the `async` from the function definition in the first example you will get the same result because the function does not need the `async` because it does not require an `await`. What you could do to have the same result has the second example is by adding a `await` before the `new Promise`.

**Note:** You also do not need the `async` in the second example because you are not waiting for anything, you are just returning a `Promise` in which you wait outside the scope.